# Replacement for Association in the following case

Tags: performance-tuning, syntax, associations

Consider the following three integrals:

```
Integral1[x_, y_] := 
 NIntegrate[Exp[-x^2. z + y*t], {z, 0, 9}, {t, -3, 4}]
Integral2[x_, y_] := 
 NIntegrate[Exp[-x^2. z + y*t]*Sin[x*z^4]*t, {z, 0, 9}, {t, -3, 4}]
Integral3[x_, y_] := 
 NIntegrate[Exp[-x^2. z + y*t]/Sqrt[
  x^2*z^2 + y^2*t^4], {z, 0, 9}, {t, -3, 4}]
```

I want to associate it with the labels "a", "b", and "c" correspondingly:

```
IntegralValues[x_, y_, label_] := 
 Association[{{x, y, "a"} -> Integral1[x, y], {x, y, "b"} -> 
     Integral2[x, y], {x, y, "c"} -> Integral3[x, y]}][{x, y, label}]
```

This dumb way leads to slowing down of the evaluation since the association calls three integrals simultaneously:

```
Integral1[1, 2] // AbsoluteTiming
IntegralValues[1, 2, "a"] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.0171722, 1490.29}
>
> {0.421919, 1490.29}

I.e. the evaluation of the first integral (the fastest one) is accompanied by evaluating of the second and the third integrals which are much slower.

Could you please tell me what the analog of `Association` in this case is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `HoldForm` to the integrals:

```
Integral1[x_, y_] := 
HoldForm[NIntegrate][Exp[-x^2. z + y*t], {z, 0, 9}, {t, -3, 4}]
Integral2[x_, y_] := 
HoldForm[NIntegrate][
Exp[-x^2. z + y*t]*Sin[x*z^4]*t, {z, 0, 9}, {t, -3, 4}]
Integral3[x_, y_] := 
HoldForm[NIntegrate][
Exp[-x^2. z + y*t]/Sqrt[x^2*z^2 + y^2*t^4], {z, 0, 9}, {t, -3, 4}]
```

We associate as follows:

```
IntegralValues[x_, y_, label_] := 
ReleaseHold@Lookup[Association[{"a" -> Integral1[x, y], "b" -> Integral2[x, y], 
"c" -> Integral3[x, y]}], label]
```

Test:

```
IntegralValues[1, 2, "a"] // AbsoluteTiming
```